# Ethernet problem after upgrading to 13.04 wired connection

Tags: ethernet

I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 but now I do not have an Ethernet connection. I upgraded just an hour ago. Is there a way to enable or check the hardware to see if my card is supported. I need help as I use this machine as my main machine for work. And I access this from the Internet VNC if I'm out.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Can you boot your old kernel (hold shift while booting, to get to the boot menu, that never works for me and i end up editing grub settings) and see if it works on it, if that works you can download a [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater) and see if a newer one works for on it, if you need to use a usb to get the mainline kernel, here is the [link](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) for that

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well as an hdmi audio issue, but upgrading my kernel to version 3.9 fixed both of them.